# Every manifold has unique orientation in base ring Z/2

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

How is it that every manifold has a unique $\mathbb{Z}/2$ orientation? Came across the more general conversation [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10966/two-kinds-of-orientability-orientation-for-a-differentiable-manifold) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12432/meaning-of-orientation-orientability-over-rings-other-than-the-integers) (they're linked).

I'm familiar with Hatcher's Algebraic Topology which has the local orientability defintion: A local $R$ orientation of $X$ at $x$ is a choice of a generator of the $R$-module $H_n(X,X−x)$.

Comment: Well there is only one generator of $H_n(X,X-x;\Bbb Z/2)$, so its essentially that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An orientation, as defined by Hatcher, is a function $\mu$ assigning to each $x \in M $ a generator $\mu_x$ of $H_n(M,M \setminus \{x\};R) \approx R$ which satisfies a suitable local consistency condition.

$\mathbb Z_2$ has only one generator, thus there is only *one* function $\mu$ and the consistency condition is automatically satisfied. If $R$ has more than one generator, then the local consistency condition gives a serious restriction on the function $\mu$.